# bash_history file and history command showing different entries

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I am using the Terminal app on OS X to try and clear my command history. The entries within my `$HOME/.bash_history` file do not match what is returned by the `history` command. The `echo $0` command tells me that my Terminal session is using the bash shell (`-bash`) so I would expect these to be the same.

Also, the `history -c` command only clears the history that I see in the Terminal app with the `history` command, it doesn't affect the contents of the `$HOME/.bash_history` file. Please could someone help to explain my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, apologies, I just realised that the command history is cached in memory until the terminal session is exited cleanly. The `$HOME/.bash_history` file and `history` command now match as expected.